# Can't find activities and Fragments inside java folder in android studio ide

Tags: android-studio, android-activity, fragment, creation

I'm new to android development and I was creating a project when I met with this issue.
**.Whenever I try to create a fragment(Blank Fragment) or another activity,they don't show up in the java folder.I have tried to find them in search bar but it shows no such file.The few seconds after creation,I see the gradle build and processes running but don't know where the files go after that.I tried to recreate them multiple times but no results.I tried many solutions such as syncing project with gradle and invalidate cache/restart but couldn't solve the issue.The problem is that it doesn't even show an error or warning in case if something is wrong with gradle or ide.The gradle build is finished perfectly but
I can't understand why the activities and fragments are not created**

I tried to recreate the project after deleting previous one and also restarted ide but couldn't fix my issue.I have been stuck here for whole day and couldn't build a single project.

If any of you can help me solve my issue,it would mean a lot as I have already wasted my whole day.

**I didn't write a single line of XMl or Java code as I was about to create other activities and fragments beside default activity for my project when I met with this issue.There is nothing in layout and Java file other than default code and no issues in those files,thus I'm not posting them.**

**Project tree is shown below.**

[image: Project Tree]

Answer (score 0):

Have you explored the project folder, if any activity/fragment files are created or not. Note: in file explorer . Pls update, screenshot of project tree

Comment: Hey I have add snapshot of project tree as you can see in java file only Main Activity and Class are shown.By the way,I can create classes without any problem but face problem  while creating activities and fragments.I opened the project in file explorer and found no activities or fragments which I created.

Comment: @SvaSva are you looking for layout files, if yes then they in res->layout->activity_main.xml. pls have a look and update

Comment: No I'm talking about java folder.I can create classes without any issue but when I try to create an activity or any fragment ,gradle starts building and is also finished but those files are not created.It never happened before

Comment: By the way,I have already mentioned that default activity is present but those that I want to create can't be created,same case with fragments.I can only create classes and layout files.I didn't do anything.The problem may be with settings of my IDE but I can't figure out

Comment: @SvaSva generally a clean install of the ide, no specific setting is required unless changed. I would recommend a clean install of the ide, follows by removing of following folders from the following path : C:\Users\<ActiveUser>\.android, C:\Users\<ActiveUser>\.AndroidStudio4.0 and finally C:\Users\<ActiveUser>\.gradle.